# How to upload csv file into server memory for passing it?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have SCV file, and i want to insert records from that file in to database, i dont wan to store/upload this file on server hard drive, i want to just parse this in memory and insert records in to database how can i do it in asp.net mvc 3.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just copy it into a memory stream:

```
if (Request.Files.Count == 1)
{
    System.IO.MemoryStream memStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
    Request.Files[0].InputStream.CopyTo(memStream);
```